# Sumar el valor entre dos input en AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<label>Capital
  <input type="number" ng-model="vm.capital" ng-keyup="vm.total()">
</label>

<label>Honorarios
  <input type="number" ng-model="vm.honorarium" ng-keyup="vm.total()">
</label>


<h1>{{ vm.sum }}</h1>
```

La función :

```
this.total = function(){
    this.sum = capital + honorarium;
}
```

Necesito hacer la suma entre capital y honorarium. Pero mi solución no funciona, quizas tengo algún problema en la lógica.

Comment: La función (método) está en la clase correcta? ¿Qué es vm? ¿Los datos se guardan correctamente en capitar y honorarium? Deberías añadir más detalles

Comment: Probablemente necesites cambiar la linea de suma a `this.sum = this.capital + this.honorarium;` a menos que capital y honorarium no sean miembros del controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si es lo unico que requieres puedes utilizarlo de la Siguiente Manera

```
   <label>
        Capital
        <input type="number" ng-model="capital">
    </label>

    <label>
        Honorarios
        <input type="number" ng-model="honorarium">
    </label>


    <h1>{{capital + honorarium }}</h1>
```

no necesitas utilizar ninguna Funcion ng-X para que haga este proceso, recuerda que estas Variables se mantienen en el $scope, quien se encarga de actualizar la informacion de ellas de manera inmediata ..

lo que haces dentro de los h1 solo es sumar lo que se contiene en tu ng-model ..

Comment: lo resolvi de manera similar, gracias!

Comment: Perfecto, la idea del ejemplo es solo realizar lo que necesitabas en el momento .. si reuqieres funciones hay otras formas .. Recuerdos !!